# Update value with JNA Structure

Tags: java, structure, jna

ok, what I need is to change the value of the structure containing the variable "Sorter", since by default contains the value 0, then I need to pass a check to a pocket other than 0. whose value is 1-12.

therefore need someone to tell me how I can write to memory a value which comes from a structure through JNA.

this structure in C is the next:

```
typedef struct _S_CODELINE_INFO_LS800

{

      // Parameter filled by LsApi

      char                 CodelineRead[CODE_LINE_LENGTH];  // Codeline returned
      short                 NrBytes;    //Length of the codeline

      // Parameter compiled from Application
      short                 Sorter;       // Sorter where put the document
      .....
} S_CODELINE_INFO_LS800, *LPS_CODELINE_INFO_LS800;
```

I have created structure and functioning properly but only I can not change the value of the sorter.

I need something like this ..

sorter before = 0
sorter after = [value between 1-12]

the problem is that for example with this method.

```
CodelineInfo.readField("Sorter");
CodelineInfo.writeField("Sorter", Short.valueOf("3"));
CodelineInfo.write();
```

I can only get the number changed ecplise console but does not change the structure.

Comment: You should edit your question for clarity.  It's really not clear what you're asking.  Simplify.

Comment: nevermind i solve the problem just need three protected method from Structure native if any want the methods are 

protected ByReference newByReference() { return new ByReference(); }
protected ByValue newByValue() { return new ByValue(); }
protected S_CODELINE_INFO_LS800 newInstance() { return new S_CODELINE_INFO_LS800(); }