# JAVA-JNA : I can't modify a structure field throughout a callback function

Tags: java, callback, jna

I have a problem with JNA callbacks. In my JAVA program I use a function pointer that will be called by a native library. This function pointer is:

```
public int callback(S_CODELINE_INFO codelineInfo)
{
    try
    {
    String codeline=new String(codelineInfo.CodelineRead);
    System.out.println("Codeline document : "+codeline); // Reading from DLL is ok

    // Set field Sorter (JAVA --> DLL)
    codelineInfo.writeField("Sorter", 9); // Writing is KO. The sorted field (sort type) is always equal to 0

    }catch(Exception exp)
    {

    exp.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

***_CODELINE_INFO structure :***

```
public class S_CODELINE_INFO extends Structure
{
   /************** Parameters compiled from LS500.dll ************************/

    // Size of the struct
    public short Size;  

    // Progessive document number
    public NativeLong NrDoc;

    // Codeline returned    
    public byte[] CodelineRead=new byte[39];    

    // Length of the codeline
    public short NrBytes;   

    // Reserved for future use
    public NativeLong Reserved;                     

    /****************** Parameters compiled from Application *********************/

    // Sorter where put the document
    public short Sorter;    

    // Set from application NORMAL or BOLD
    public byte FormatString;       

    // String to print rear of the document
    public String StringToPrint;

    public S_CODELINE_INFO()
    {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() 
    {
        return Arrays.asList(new String[]{
            "Size", "NrDoc", "CodelineRead", "NrBytes", "Reserved", "Sorter","FormatString", "StringToPrint"        
        });
    }

    public static class ByReference extends S_CODELINE_INFO implements Structure.ByReference{};

}
```

Comment: What is the question?  What error is happening?

Comment: I can't modify the field Sorter. The native libary receives always the 0 value

Comment: The field Sorter is a field that be setted by Java application in order to be used by the native library

Comment: I can not change the value of the sorter field. Any idea to resolve this problem ?

Comment: Your question has been up less than 24 hours. It's possible none of the 20 people who have seen it knows how to answer it.  To get your question in front of more JNA experts, including the JNA project maintainers who may not visit here frequently, I suggest you ask your question on the [JNA Mailing List.](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jna-users)

Comment: Where/how are you reading the value of the field changed in the callback?

Comment: The native library logs the value of the field changed.

Comment: I  found this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18832186/update-value-with-jna-structure - but the problem persists

Comment: `Sorter` is of type `short` (2 bytes).  Your Java code is writing a 4 bytes `int` to it.  Depending on endianness it may be getting the two high order bytes. Try casting: `codelineInfo.writeField("Sorter", (short) 9)`

Comment: Same problem with  codelineInfo.writeField("Sorter",(short) 2); In DLL logs  i have 00:33:52.768 2020 - 2696 - ReadCodelineAndSort_Ls5xx - infoCodeline.Sorter = 0

Comment: Check your other mappings.  The 39 you have for `CodeLineRead` doesn't match the 256 I'm seeing in the native structure.

Comment: Good. It works fine now. i changed the size of CodeLineRead. Thanks Daniel. I have one question : Where did you see 256 bytes ??

Comment: https://blogs.msmvps.com/montaque/2004/04/01/convert-c-code-to-c/

Comment: Also it looks like JNA might have converted the int to short anyway, but it's still better to use `new Short()` explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are modifying the structure, just not in the way you intended.

JNA's `Structure` class maps its Java fields to appropriate offsets in native memory for the C `struct` equivalent.

In this case, the way you have defined the structure, you are attempting to write the `Sorter` field, a `short` (2-byte) field at an offset of 51 bytes from the beginning of the structure.

However, this may not be where `Sorter` is on the native side.  I'm not sure where your `39` came from, but the native code I see online has:

```
char CodelineRead[CODE_LINE_LENGTH]; // Codeline returned
```

With that value defined:

```
#define CODE_LINE_LENGTH 256 // Max length of returned codeline
```

So writing at bytes 51-52 doesn't work since you're writing in the middle of the `CodeLineRead` array on the native side.

Comment: The same problem with codelineInfo.writeField("Sorter",(short) 2). In DLL logs i have  00:33:52.768 2020 - 2696 - ReadCodelineAndSort_Ls5xx - infoCodeline.Sorter = 0

Comment: I've updated my answer based on the wrong length of the CodeLineRead array.